# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL: Token "06061c" is invalid

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm using a SQL clause in a PostgreSQL database with PDO. I have a function that generates a verification code and another that updates the user's code. However, there is an issue in this function that updates the code. It identifies it as a token when the code contains letters. If it's only numbers or only letters, it updates perfectly. I've read in some posts that it's necessary to enclose my field with quotes, but it doesn't work with parameters.

```
public function upCode(Usuario $user){
    try {
        var_dump($user->getCode());
        $sql = "UPDATE usuarios
        SET usuario = jsonb_set(usuario, '{code}', :code, false)
        WHERE usuario->>'email' = :email";
        $stmt = (parent::getCon())->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue("email", $user->getEmail());
        $stmt->bindValue("code", $user->getCode(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

    }catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "". $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

```
public function gerarCode(){
        $this->code = bin2hex(random_bytes(3));
    }
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input
> syntax for type json DETAIL: Token "06061c" is invalid. CONTEXT: JSON
> data, line 1: 06061c unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'

But if I try this way, it works.

```
$stmt->bindValue("code", "456478", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: jsonb_set() expects a valid piece of json for the first and third parameter, it looks like the third parameter :code isn't valid json. Could you share the content of `$user->getCode()` ?

Comment: var_dump($user->getCode()); Output:
/var/www/html/src/Service/SQL/Update/UpdateUser.php:27:string 'ceec13' (length=6) method:
    public function getCode(): string{
        return $this->code;
    }

Comment: I also tried with cast :code::jsonb, but it doesn't work

Comment: If I tried to put the code manually without the parameters then '"456f8h"' and it worked, but this "456f8h" didn't work, I tried escaping the quotes with the parameter, but it doesn't work

Comment: 'ceec13' is a string, not a piece of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [to_jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSINGhttps://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING)() to create valid jsonb for the new value:

```
UPDATE usuarios
SET usuario = jsonb_set(usuario, '{code}', to_jsonb(CAST(:code AS text)), false)
WHERE usuario->>'email' = :email;
```

Also CAST the content to TEXT, to be very explicit to the database about how to handle the input.